# Incomplete Google App Engine Documentation on Conversion API

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to convert a HTML string into a .PNG file. Thanks to [Nick Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson) who pointed me to [GAE Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview) see previous post  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720409/gwt-generate-image-from-html-string-png-jpeg).

I use the [GAE Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview)
which works but my images in my HTML string doesn't display.

In the Documentation on  [GAE Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/overview) there is a reference to `Adding Assets` and a mention of `static/icon.gif` which I think may address my problem but that documentation is incomplete.

Can anyone please assist?

My HTML conversion to .PNG works but all images e.g

`<img src="http://mydomain.com/image.gif>` doesn't print yet `http://mydomain.com/image.gif` is available.

Thanks

PB

**Update 1:**
According to the documentation, I should create seperate asset for each image and name must match the src attr.

```
 List<Asset>assets = new ArrayList<Asset>();    
        try {
            Asset asset = new Asset("text/html", notification.getMessage().getBytes("UTF-8"), "testfile.html");
            assets.add(asset);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {      
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**winningNumbers is just a number, expecting 5 0r 6 numbers**

```
    for (String n : winningNumbers) {
                String url = "http://www.someURL.com/img/balls/" + n +".gif";
                Asset e = new Asset("image/gif", loadGIFByte(url), url);            
                assets.add(e); 

}




 Document document = new Document(assets);  
//Here I want to convert everything, the images and html to a .PNG MIMETYPE.    
            Conversion conversion = new Conversion(document, "image/png");
            ConversionService service =          ConversionServiceFactory.getConversionService();
            ConversionResult conversionResult = service.convert(conversion);


private byte[] loadGIFByte(String urlGIF) {
    System.out.println("Loading GIF for "+ urlGIF);
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1536];
    int count = 0;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(urlGIF);
        InputStream reader = u.openStream();
        while ((count = reader.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);           
            }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

return buf;
}
    }
```

**Update 2:**
A typical notification.getMessage() should return;

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
/** Add css rules here for your application. *//** Example rules used by the template application (remove for your app) */h1 {  font-size: 2em;  font-weight: bold;  color: #777777;  margin: 40px 0px 70px;  text-align: center;}.sendButton {  display: block;  font-size: 16pt;}/** Most GWT widgets already have a style name defined */.gwt-DialogBox {  width: 400px;}.dialogVPanel {  margin: 5px;}.serverResponseLabelError {  color: red;}/** Set ids using widget.getElement().setId("idOfElement") */#closeButton {  margin: 15px 6px 6px;}.usefulLinksUL{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;display:block;font-weight:bold;#background-color:#FFD700;width:180px;}.usefulLinksAnchor{a:link,a:visited;text-decoration:none;a:hover,a:active;}.note {font-size: 80%;background-color: #FEF49E;/**background-color: #d8da3d;*/border: 1px solid #D0C98D;-webkit-box-shadow: -8px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}.note-title {margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;padding: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;background-color: #D0C98D;color: white;font-weight: bolder;}.note-content {margin: 5px;background: transparent;border: none;overflow: hidden;}.container { width:50px; overflow:hidden }.cube { width:150px; height:150px; float:left;}#rounded-corner{  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;    font-size: 12px;    margin: 5px;    /*width: 180px;*/   text-align: left;   border-collapse: collapse;}#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-company{    background: #b9c9fe url('img/latestResult/left.png') left -1px no-repeat;}#rounded-corner thead th.rounded-q4{  background: #b9c9fe url('img/latestResult/right.png') right -1px no-repeat;}#rounded-corner th{ padding: 8px;   font-weight: normal;    font-size: 13px;    color: #039;    background: #b9c9fe;}#rounded-corner td{    padding: 8px;   background: #e8edff;    border-top: 1px solid #fff; color: #669;}#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-left{    background: #e8edff url('img/latestResult/botleft.png') left bottom no-repeat;}#rounded-corner tfoot td.rounded-foot-right{ background: #e8edff url('img/latestResult/botright.png') right bottom no-repeat;}#rounded-corner tbody tr:hover td{ background: #d0dafd;}.latestLotto{  background-color: #C3D9FF;  border: 1px solid #87B3FF;  cursor: default; }.bbottomyello {border-bottom: 1px solid #CFA55B;}.onGreenBackground {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: white;font-style: normal;}.btopbottomYellow {border-top: 1px solid #FFCB05;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFCB05;}.bbottomYellow {border-bottom: 1px solid #FFCB05;}h3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #EB0900;} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 

<table width="100%" height="123" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor = "#FFFFFF"> 
            <tbody><tr> 
                <td width="47%" class="bbottomyello"><img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/lotto_top_left_home.gif" alt=""></td> 
                <td width="16%" class="bbottomyello">&nbsp;</td> 
                <td colspan="3" valign="top" class="bbottomYellow">&nbsp;</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#00A452">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="onGreenBackground"><span class="onGreenBackground">Wednesday, June 13 2012</span></span></td> 
                <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#00A452" class="onGreenBackground">Latest Results: Confirmed</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td height="23" colspan="5" class="btopbottomYellow">&nbsp;<strong>&nbsp;Winning Numbers</strong></td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td height="31" colspan="2" class="bbottomYellow"> 
                <div align="center"> 
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/9.gif" width="30" height="40">  
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/20.gif" width="30" height="40">  
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/14.gif" width="30" height="40">  
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/16.gif" width="30" height="40">  
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/43.gif" width="30" height="40">  
                    <img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/41.gif" width="30" height="40"> 
                    </div> 
                    </td> 
                <td width="12%" height="31" valign="middle" class="bbottomYellow"><h3>Bonus<br> 
                    Ball:</h3></td> 
                <td width="14%" class="bbottomYellow"> <div align="center"><img src="http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/13.gif" width="34" height="40"></div></td>                 
            </tr> 
            </tbody></table></body> 

</html>
```

Notification class signature is:

```
public class Notification implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8464293752450599178L;
    private Result result;
    private NotificationClientType client;
    private String message;
    private String api_key;
    private String secret_key;
    private String deliveryAddress; //e.g email, fax etc
    public NotificationClientType getClient() {
        return client;
    }
    public void setClient(NotificationClientType client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getApi_key() {
        return api_key;
    }
    public void setApi_key(String api_key) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
    }
    public String getSecret_key() {
        return secret_key;
    }
    public void setSecret_key(String secret_key) {
        this.secret_key = secret_key;
    }
    public String getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }
    public void setDeliveryAddress(String deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }
    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
```

Some Feedback.
No difference in result. I guess return out.toByteArray() solved NPE which I accidentally caused.

The expected result is below: The same HTML string sent as email yields:
[image: expected result]

GAE conversion result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview#Additional_Functions) says that the name of the asset should match the src attribute of the img tag.

Here is a python code I tried in the interactive console, and it actually produced the two images

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine.api import conversion

url = "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/77186109/favicon_reasonably_small.png"
asset = conversion.Asset("text/html", '<b>some data</b><br/><img src="a.png"/><img src="%s"/><br/>Foo' % url, "test.html")
conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "image/png")

img_response = urlfetch.fetch(url)
image1 = conversion.Asset('image/png', img_response.content, "a.png")
image2 = conversion.Asset('image/png', img_response.content, url)
conversion_obj.add_asset(image1)
conversion_obj.add_asset(image2)

result = conversion.convert(conversion_obj)
print result.error_text

print repr(result.assets[0].data)
```

Comment: hi @skreft, thanks for your input, What I am doing is similar to yours, I have updated my Question with some source code for you to see. Maybe this works within the python env and not Java ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your method loadGIFByte is returning the wrong thing. You are returning the buffer, which will contain only part of the image. You should return out.toByteArray(). Also, could you post part of your html (your notification variable).

Comment: Hi Again, thanks for helping, much appreciated, I have updated my post for clarity. In the mean time, while I wait for further suggestions from you, I will try out.toByteArray(). and give feedback.

Comment: Also note that the url you are generating is of the form url = "http://www.someURL.com/img/balls/" + n +".gif", but the url in the html file is "http://mylottoshop.appspot.com//img/balls/9.gif" (Note the double slash). You need to have exactly the same string for both the name of the asset and the src attribute. Also would you remove the other question you posted since it is a duplicate.

Comment: Unbelievable! Works!! Thanks a billion @skreft , you are a superstar!